# WebSocket doesn't work in Aptana Studio 2.0

Tags: javascript, websocket, aptana

I need to write an application in Aptana Studio 2.0 and there is a problem.
This line, where I want to create a new WebSocket causes an error (pic).
`var websocket = new WebSocket(URI);`
Error:
[image: Error]

How could I solve this?

Comment: Start by updating your IDE

Comment: @sdespont it is my studies project, need to be written in Aptana 2.0. But if it's impossible to avoid update, I will do this.